# Can Jekyll use a config file from a different repo

Tags: github, documentation, jekyll, github-pages

I'm using Jekyll and GitHub Pages to create documentation for projects that live in separate repos that are part of an organization account in GitHub. My team has decided it makes the most sense for the docs to live in each repo alongside the code, so we'll be using a gh-pages branch in each repo.

I will also be setting up a separate gh-pages repo from the organization account to serve as a landing page. I'd like to have all of my jekyll config items live in this repo. What do I need to put in the config file in each of the repos to successfully pull all of the layouts, css/scss, etc. from this central location? Is this even possible?

[Here's a visual representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hccMz.png)

**In a nutshell**, I'm trying to have one place where I can make changes to the website formatting files instead of 6.

Answer (score 5):

On Github pages, you can use resources from another repository by using [git submodules](https://help.github.com/articles/using-submodules-with-pages/).

This works well for `_layouts` and `_sass`, but sadly not for `_includes`. This due to the fact that, in Jekyll 2.x, [you cannot configure _includes folder path](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/2684). This has been committed in the current master and will be available as soon as Jekyll 3 is out and used by github pages.

**Edit**: With Jekyll 3, you can now configure `includes_dir: _mydir`. See [documentation for Jekyll configuration](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/#default-configuration).

An interim solution can be to merge includes in layouts until you're able to configure `_includes` path. Not so clean, but, as your templates a centralized, it will be easy to refactor.

### Howto

#### 1 - create a resources repository

Adding your organization repository as a submodule will pull both resources, post and pages. Not a good way to go because posts and pages will be present in your project blogs.

The better way is to hosts your resources (`_includes`, `_layouts`, `_sass`, `css`) in a dedicated repository at `github.com/userName/resources`.

In your `_layouts/default.html`, dont forget to call you css with :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ "/resources/css/main.css" | prepend: site.baseurl }}">
```

#### 2 - Project blog Setup

Create a project blog without resources files and add the resources submodule.

```
git submodule add https://github.com/userName/resources.git
```

This creates a `resources` folder in you repository.

Edit your `_config.yml` and add:

```
layouts:  /resources/_layouts
sass:
    sass_dir: /resources/_sass
```

You can now `jekyll serve`, it works.

#### 3 - Resources workflow

As your resources are in a submodule, changes in a template or sass file will not be reflected in your blog automatically.

In order to refresh your blog you will have to do this for all your blogs.

```
git submodule update --remote
git commit -a -m 'resources update'
git push origin gh-pages
```

Comment: Can we configure _includes folder path on the Jekyll 3? I cannot find the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

After getting feedback from my team, I ended up doing the following:

- create new repo that will be the source of the GH-Pages site
- add the individual project repos as submodules of this repo
- add a script that tells jekyll to pull content from specific folders in the submodules and place them in a temp dir, then use that temp dir as the build source

`#remove docs-build-temp folder if it exists`

`rm -rf ./docs-build-temp`

`#make temp-content folder`

`mkdir ./docs-build-temp`

`#copy content from doc folder in submodules into temp-content folder`

`cp -R ./submodule1/doc ./docs-build-temp/newdir1`

`cp -R ./submodule2/doc ./docs-build-temp/newdir2`

`#tell jekyll the content source`

`bundle exec jekyll build -s ./docs-build-temp`

The script works when run locally and in Travis CI*.

*I set up ssh authentication between my user acct in github and each of the repos in travis to get around the fact that all of them are private. Seems to be working out ok so far.